# Cypress Error in sending multiple parameters via CLI

Tags: command-line, automated-tests, environment-variables, parameter-passing, cypress

1. I'm using below command in my terminal.([Im following the cypress support doc](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-4-env))

cypress run --env host=kevin.dev.local,api_server=http://localhost:8888/api/v1

2. my spec is like this.

[image]

3. I'm expecting to set variables as below:

```
host=kevin.dev.local
```

```
api_server=http://localhost:8888/api/v1
```

4. But it does not set the value of the "api_server". Instead it sets host with both values as below:

```
host=kevin.dev.local http://localhost:8888/api/v1
```

Pls support to get this resolved.

[image]

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems there, and it works on my windows machine without issues, if that's of any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shell might interpret some of the characters before passing them to Cypress.

When I run in Powershell the following command:

```
> cypress open --env a=1,b=2
```

I'll end up in the same situation like described.

When I run:

```
> cypress open --env "a=1,b=2"
```

It will correctly set two env variables `a` and `b` with correct values.

So, try using double quotes.

Comment: It worked with double quotes, Thanks a lot :)